# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSch error in JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jsch

I wrote a program that connect to remote LINUX machine and executes a command. I used `jsch-0.1.42.jar` file to connect to remote machine. My program working well and returning output. Now I would like to call method, which is declare inside in Servlet from JSP using the following code

```
<% SSHCommandExecutor sshce = new SSHCommandExecutor();
sshce.runCommnad();
%>
```

But I am getting following error

```
HTTP Status 500 -java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSch Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
```

Comment: "I have added the jar but getting the error", then you have not added the jar. please tell what you did to add the jar.

Comment: and please post the whole jsp.

Comment: @Yevgeniy: I am using eclipse for my development. I have added jar by right click on project-->build path -->configure build path -->add external jars and added the jar.

Comment: @rejesh how do you deploy the application to the servlet container? do you use the server-view in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the class inside your jsp page before using it as we import the class in normal java class.

Just the method to import is different.

We import the class in normal java class files just after the `package` statement( if `package` statement exist) or as the first statement.

In jsp we mention the `import` attribute in the `page` directive like this :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"   

import="com.jcraft.jsch.JSch"%>

the above lines comes at the top of the jsp page

.... 

rest of the jsp page
```

Comment: @ Abu: Thanks for your reply. I have added import statement but no luck. still same error

Comment: where have you out your jar file, I mean inside which folder ?

Comment: I have added jar by right click on project-->build path -->configure build path -->add external jars and added the jar(using eclipse)

Comment: just try putting the jar file first in `WEb-INF\lib` folder of your webapp and then add it by right click on project... the same method you wrote in above comment.

Comment: working great.  Thanks for your valuable time and suggestion.